# Insert image into text input

Tags: android, keyboard, textview, android-image

I'd like to be able to build an Android application that can insert an image into a text input of any application. The problem is that I don't control the way the text with the image is displayed, I can only control how the text with image is sent to the text input. I haven't seen anything like this and tried those solutions with no success :

- Spannable : only works if you can control the receiving `EditText` or `TextView`
- Keyboard : sending a `SpannableStringBuilder` on special key : only works in the application that contains the image. Doesn't work when loading an image from phone storage : still only works in the keyboard app.
- Clipboard : only pastes the uri of the image
- Emoji : system or application emojis

Do you know how I can achieve this ?